Movie that ends with a couple (who were possibly criminals) in a burning building
It would have to be from the 80's or 90's, because I believe I watched it in the mid to late 90's. Also, the movie was American.
Unfortunately, all I remember is the ending:
There were two adults-- male and female, whom I assume to be 'bad' like criminals of some sort. They were both I want to say dressed in black, and are a couple. Both of them looked to have been injured, and perhaps are just giving up or surrendering to what is happening. They're in a bigger building, kind of empty like a warehouse. The woman and man are sitting next to each other behind like a brick column. People, possibly cops are converging on them and the building was on fire. 
I remember the credits start playing with a aerial shot of the building in the background with smoke coming out. I thought for a while the song 'I Would Do Anything for Love' by Meatloaf was playing during the credits, but I am not sure now.
Definitely not the older-Zorro like costumes, I would say more modern. The woman was definitely wearing black pants, if that helps at all... I am just picturing them both wearing black, not like crazy armor suits or anything just black pants, shirt, etc. 

It's not a perfect match, but your description has some interesting parallels to the ending of Fight Club.




No, I've seen that a bunch, definitely not that one. Thanks though!

Don't remember the ending exactly, but it feels like "Mr and Mrs Smith" with Brad Pitt and Angelina Jolie? The had some shooting scene in a warehouse and lots of incoming armed people.

It ends with them in the shrink's office, though.

but wasn't that after the credits? nvm, just the first thing that popped into my mind.

That movie is too new. As stated in my question, it would have to be a movie from the 90's or earlier. Thank you though!
